# jQuery-Ajax dont work on production server

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I 've created a web application, the basic idea was to have one page and then with ajax insert data from php-mysql script. On local Xampp the application works perfect.

On production server some ajax requests work but others dont work.

Chrome inspect element shows error:

```
POST mysite.com/app/show_staff_profile_ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.0.3.js:7845
send  jquery-2.0.3.js:7845
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-2.0.3.js:7301
showProfile ajax.js:466
(anonymous function) ajax.js:150
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.3.js:4676
elemData.handle jquery-2.0.3.js:4360
```

On ajax.js line 150 i got:

```
$(document).on('click','.show_profile',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    showProfile(id);  //line 150
    return false;
});
```

And on line 446:

```
function showProfile(id){
    $.ajax({   //line 446
        type:"POST",
        url: "show_staff_profile_ajax.php",
        data: {id : id},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#program_panel").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

On show_staff_profile_ajax.php i am taking data from mysql and *echo:* **html tags with php variables**.

I am trying two days to fix that issue. I have read many posts but nothing seems to work

Comment: Normally, 500 errors happen due to some issue in the server side. Also. check if the node with `.show_profile` has an ID attribute.

Comment: Try posting the data in a browser on the server itself so you see the actual error, as a 500 error just means "something went wrong".  If you run it on the server it should give you more information.

Comment: it's weird...i made a fiddle and its working.. http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/mw2rt/

Comment: ok I found it, the problem was server-side in the show_staff_profile_ajax.php file. There is a DateTime object that is causing the problem. Thank everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 error means there is a an error in your show_staff_profile_ajax.php file. Try to get more information on that - there is usually an error log file for php apps. Find it and it will probably give you more information about what caused the error.

The only data you are passing in the ajax calls is "id" so I would look at that too. Maybe put a line like this:

```
console.log('profile id: ' + id);
```

just before you run showProfile(id) in your click function. There may be some HTML elements with incorrect data-id values. This should display the id in your console just before the error occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the problem was in the show_staff_profile_ajax.php with a DateTime Object.

Answer (score 1):

As karhikr has said, a 500 error indicates that the error is on your server, not in their browser.

Xampp is a Windows package, Windows is case insensitive and relaxed about write permissions - if moving the site to a Linux environment has broken it then the likelihood is that that's where your problem is - a 500 error is more likely to be a write permission error than a capitalisation one.

Comment: I set the permitiossions to 777, this wasn't the problem but Thank anyway.